# SQL db inserting to table works with 1 item but not multiple

Tags: python, sql

I have a sql database Im trying to write too via a python script. That python script parses DC switches then spits it out into results_list. I then filter for the below 2 items description and interface.

The front end of the app is a flask page I have buttons assigned that will query x cabinet and do all the above. I want to send all of below data to a sql database. I also want to prevent duplicates / update table if item has changed.

right now when i run the query if the working params gets passed on to sql and the rest of the flask script is processed. When I pass params with multiple items I get the following error.

```
OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

working params:

```
params = ([('TECH2_5750',)], [('Gi1/0/7',)], [(u'10.210.44.5',)])
```

not working params:

```
params = ([('TECH2_5252',), ('TECH2_5261',), ('TECH2_5857',), ('TECH2_5278',), ('TECH2_5855',), ('TECH2_5207',), ('TECH2_6539',), ('TECH2_6363',), ('TECH2_5253',), ('TECH2_5030',), ('TECH2_6575',), ('TECH2_5839',), ('TECH2_6953',), ('TECH2_6133',), ('TECH2_5046',), ('TECH2_6152',), ('TECH2_5267',), ('TECH2_5847',), ('TECH2_5748',), ('TECH2_5104',), ('TECH2_5649',), ('TECH2_5103',)], [('Gi2/0/11',), ('Gi1/0/11',), ('Gi2/0/7',), ('Gi3/0/27',), ('Gi1/0/7',), ('Gi2/0/9',), ('Gi3/0/7',), ('Gi2/0/27',), ('Gi1/0/29',), ('Gi3/0/25',), ('Gi2/0/25',), ('Gi2/0/29',), ('Gi2/0/31',), ('Gi1/0/31',), ('Gi2/0/5',), ('Gi1/0/25',), ('Gi1/0/5',), ('Gi3/0/5',), ('Gi1/0/9',), ('Gi1/0/35',), ('Gi1/0/27',), ('Gi1/0/33',)], [(u'10.210.45.5',)])
```

code:

```
local1 = []
device1 = []
items = len(filtered_interface)
for item in range(0, items):
    t = filtered_tech[item].split(' ')
    hostname = t[1]
    device1.append((hostname,))
    t = filtered_interface[item].split(' ')
    interfacelocal = t[1]
    local1.append((interfacelocal,))
cab1 = []
cab1.append((cab,))
params = (device1,  local1, cab1,)
connection1 = MySQLdb.connect(user="user", passwd="password", db="db",host="127.0.0.1")
mycursor = connection1.cursor()
sql = """
        INSERT INTO devices (hostname, localint, cab) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
mycursor.execute(sql, params)
        connection1.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mycursur.execute()` requires that `params` have the same number of elements as you have placeholders in the query. Since you have 3 placeholders, `params` must have 3 elements.

If you want to insert multiple rows, you need to use `mycursor.executemany`. This will execute the query repeatedly for each element of the parameter sequence. `params` should then be a 2-dimensional sequence, with each element of the top-level sequence being a sequence of 3 parameters to fill in the placeholders.

```
params = [('TECH2_5252', 'Gi1/0/7', u'10.210.44.5'),
          ('TECH2_5261', 'Gi1/0/11', u'10.210.45.5'),
          ('TECH2_5857', 'Gi2/0/7', u'10.210.45.5'),
          ...]
sql = """
        INSERT INTO devices (hostname, localint, cab) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
mycursor.executemany(sql, params)
```

Comment: works perfectly had issue with my list needed to zip them first but then it worked as expected.